# bootstrap: best-practice- should nav be placed in a container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Should the bootstrap nav go inside a container?

I'm looking for guidance on what the best practice is.

Comment: No but the navbar may contain a `container` or `container-fluid`.. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 0):

The container simply puts a default margin on both sides of your content. It allows you to keep everything in the "article" section of the app. Even when it is not contained in the same parent div. If you need your nav to be centered with your content, then use it. But it is not required.